# Счетчик времени кулдауна работает наоборот

Tags: python, telebot, sqlite3, datetime

У меня стоит кулдаун на использование команды '/go', время когда была использована команда находится в базе данных [sqlite3](/questions/tagged/sqlite3), имеется строка с данными пользователя в колонке `get_card_cd` находится это время в формате `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f` - `2023-10-09 00:35:15.268208`. Если у пользователя команда находится в кулдауне, то ему должно писать **Осталось подождать n-ое количество времени**, в моем случае этот счетчик есть и сообщение тоже пишет, но почему то счетчик работает наоборот, начиная с нуля (Пример сообщений - Осталось подождать 0:13:00 времени и через 3 секунды - Осталось подождать 0:16:00 времени)

Как это можно решить?

```py
import telebot
import sqlite3
import datetime

bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)

sql = sqlite3.connect('database.db', check_same_thread=False)
conn = sql.cursor()


@bot.message_handler(commands=["go"])
def go(message):
    last_command_use_time = conn.execute('SELECT get_card_cd FROM users WHERE user_id={}'.format(message.chat.id)).fetchone()[0]
    x = datetime.datetime.strptime(last_command_use_time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')

    if not last_command_use_time or (datetime.datetime.now() - x).seconds/14400 > 1:
        # Если кнопка не нажималась или с прошлого запуска команды прошёл час
        conn.execute('UPDATE users SET get_card_cd=? WHERE user_id=?', (datetime.datetime.now(), message.chat.id))
        sql.commit()
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Нужное сообщение...')
    else:
        # Если же час ещё не прошёл
        seconds = (datetime.datetime.now() - x).seconds
        minutes = datetime.timedelta(minutes=seconds)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Осталось подождать {} времени'.format(minutes))


bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось все очень просто, нужно было просто поменять местами datetime.datetime.now() и x

```py
    else:
        # Если же час ещё не прошёл
        seconds = (x - datetime.datetime.now()).seconds
        minutes = datetime.timedelta(minutes=seconds)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Осталось подождать {} времени'.format(minutes))
```